# What kind of disk controller does Hyper-V need to use for a restoring a non-VM image?

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012

Every time I try to restore an image, whether it is Clonezilla or from a backup program, it always fails in Hyper-V (and VMWare).  I get a BSOD with several hex numbers, including 0x0000007b 0xc0000034.  These are innaccessible boot device errors.  My image restores fine to a physical machine.  I can load the Repair Windows program that it automatically goes into.  I have tried using bootrec; I also tried gparted and so on.

I have read a lot of things, but nothing works.  What kind of controller is Hyper-V supposed to be using?  Or what kind of controller does my OS expect from the hypervisor?  I'm using Windows 7, if it matters, and I have tried lots of registry entries concerning the *ide.sys drivers on the guest.

I do not always have a physical machine to do a P2V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Windows 7, at first, all the storage device drivers are enabled.  But, to make it boot faster, as soon as it's clear which storage devices are in the machine, all the others are disabled.

Hyper-V exposes two storage controller, IDE and a virtual SCSI controller that is specific to Hyper-V.  The boot device depends on which generation of VM you're using.  Generation 1 VMs use the IDE and Generation 2 VMs use the Hyper-V Virtual SCSI.

You have to enable one or the other in your image, and then pick the right VM type.

Comment: Do you know how I can enable them?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the vendor's official P2V program?  In VMware, that's Vmware Converter.  In Microsoft, that's Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter.  These programs are typically free utilities.

With these P2V programs, there usually is a higher success rate as the program really sets up the new virtual machine to run on the virtual hardware.  With a pure cloning program, like Clonezilla, you might not get the chance to set a specific driver back to one that is compatible with virtual hardware.